# Grabbing data using PHP from reddit.com

Tags: php, api, reddit

I'm really really new on using APIs. I have been trying to grab data from reddit to analyse them.

Currently I'm trying with a small testing code, but the data it gives is not in a order.

```
    <?php

    $array = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.reddit.com/.json"));

    foreach ($array as $key=>$string) {
                var_dump($array);
            }

    ?>
```

How the output comes with the above code

[image: How the output comes with the above code]

I don't know whether I'm taking the right approach according to my objective. So what I really want to do is **capture all new posts until we reach 10,000 and follow those posts every day to log the number of upvotes, comments and the ranking**.

Please tell some tips and guides to grab the data that I need?

Comment: I expect you'd need to parse the data structure in this JSON output and identify a post identifier, so it can be stored in the database and compared on each run of your scraping script.

Comment: thanks for the tip!! ill try and let u know

Comment: "the data it gives is not in a order" -- it's sorted by [hot](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx#L44-L58), plus [some additional logic](https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/2lhhiu/the_reddit_frontpage_is_not_a_meritocracy/clv5d5j?context=3) that's specific to the frontpage.